# Pymongo convert timestamp to date as a new field

Tags: python, mongodb, date, timestamp, pymongo

I have many entities in my collection and I have to create a new date field in collection to use for future queries.

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5afea920d326051990a7f337'), 'created_at': 'Fri May 18 10:21:07 +0000 2018', 'timestamp_ms': '1526638867739'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5afea920d326051990a7f339'), 'created_at': 'Fri May 18 10:21:08 +0000 2018', 'timestamp_ms': '1526638868310'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5afea972d326051c5c05bc11'), 'created_at': 'Fri May 18 10:22:30 +0000 2018', 'timestamp_ms': '1526638950799'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5afea974d326051c5c05bc16'), 'created_at': 'Fri May 18 10:22:32 +0000 2018', 'timestamp_ms': '1526638952160'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5afea974d326051c5c05bc17'), 'created_at': 'Fri May 18 10:22:32 +0000 2018', 'timestamp_ms': '1526638952841'}
```

I need to convert timestamp_ms into date format like this:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5afea920d326051990a7f337'), 'created_at': 'Fri May 18 10:21:07 +0000 2018', 'timestamp_ms': '1526638867739’, 'NewDate': '2018 05 18 10:21:07'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5afea920d326051990a7f339'), 'created_at': 'Fri May 18 10:21:08 +0000 2018', 'timestamp_ms': '1526638868310’, 'NewDate': '2018 05 18 10:21:08'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5afea972d326051c5c05bc11'), 'created_at': 'Fri May 18 10:22:30 +0000 2018', 'timestamp_ms': '1526638950799’, 'NewDate': '2018 05 18 10:22:30'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5afea974d326051c5c05bc16'), 'created_at': 'Fri May 18 10:22:32 +0000 2018', 'timestamp_ms': '1526638952160’, 'NewDate': '2018 05 18 10:22:32'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5afea974d326051c5c05bc17'), 'created_at': 'Fri May 18 10:22:32 +0000 2018', 'timestamp_ms': '1526638952841’, 'NewDate': '2018 05 18 10:22:32'}
```

I used this code (Python 3.6, pymongo 3.8, mongodb 4.0):

```
pipeline = [
    {
        '$addFields': {
            'newDate': {
                '$toDate': '$timestamp_ms'
            }
        }
    }
]
cursor = collection.aggregate(pipeline)
```

But gives this error message: `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Error parsing date string '1526638867739'; 12: Unexpected character '9'`

I am not sure that aggregate is the right method for this task. `datetime.strptime()` can be better for `'created_at'` but I haven't figured out how to implement it into `db.Mycollection_update_many()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer for my question from Kanika Singla at MongoDB University Discussion Forum. The answer is here, if you have same problem.

```
pipeline = [
    {
        '$project': {
            'yearMonthDayUTC': {
                '$convert': {
                    'to': 'double',
                    'input': '$timestamp_ms'
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$addFields': {
            'newDate': {
                '$toDate': '$yearMonthDayUTC'
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below  query with pymongo and mongodb 4.0

```
db.test.aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$addFields": {
                "NewDate": {"$toDate": "$timestamp_ms"} 
            }
        },
        {
            "$out": "test"
        },
    ],
)
```

Comment: Dear Amit Boke. It gives the same error code. pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Error parsing date string '1526638867739'; 12: Unexpected character '9'